# Aren't Databinding generated classes memory heavy?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Whenever I see any databinding generated class (for eg, `ActivityHomeBindingImpl.java`), I can see atleast a few `String[]`, `int[]`, `SparseIntArrays`, `WeakReference<ViewDataBinding>`, a few static classes and a `LiveDataListener`.

My question is, for small layouts aren't these generated classes Memory heavy?

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Any insights, Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They apear in the `build` folder so the short answer is No.

They might increase the compile time. But I don't think it would affect your apk.

Comment: What I understood from build folder is, build has generated code, which we would otherwise have to write. In databinding example, it has all the view instances so that we needn't write those ourselves. It will be included in the APK I guess.